# Text Not using Entire Width of Text View

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, xcode5

I have a text view in my app and the text in it looked fine in Xcode 4.6 but the text doesn't use the entire width of the text view in Xcode 5 and iOS 7.  Any ideas what is going on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be useful if you can include property/size screen for this text view in your screenshot.

Comment: I've added more screenshots.

Comment: Is it possible that you just have a CR characters before "have put" and other starts of lines?

Comment: @sha, No.  It only does this in Xcode 5 and iOS 7.  I don't have the problem in iOS 6 and Xcode 4.6

Comment: Does it look fine in run-time? Or is it broken in exactly same way? What happens when you try to change size of the view? What happens when you try to change text?

Comment: @sha, it does the same thing if I delete the text and type something else.  It looks like this in run-time as well.

Comment: When you change size of the control what happens?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43778/discussion-between-sha-and-user2029585)

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it by changing the text to plain and then back to attributed.  Not sure why there was an issue though.